# What is difference between showWindow: and makeKeyAndOrderFront: in NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

What is basic difference between `showWindow`:  and `makeKeyAndOrderFront`: methods of  `NSWindowController`.
When to go for `showWindow`: and when to go for `makeKeyAndOrderFront`:
Which is most recommended method

Comment: `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` is a method of `NSWindow`

Comment: To clarify @Willeke a bit, `showWindow:` usually ends up calling `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` for you and is suitable as an action target. It also considers special cases when working with `NSPanel` windows. But for regular windows, there's really no difference.